# expected array,compile error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

```
    For j = 0 To 20
        For i = 0 To 20

            ReDim atoms(0 To 20, 0 To 20)
            ReDim atomschange(0 To 20, 0 To 20)
            atomschange(j, i) = 0

            If i Mod 2 = 0 And j Mod 2 = 0 Then
                [B2].Offset(j, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                atoms(j, i) = 1
            Else
                [B2].Offset(j, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
                atoms(j, i) = 0
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please format your code properly. What error are you getting? What line is erroring? What have you tried?

Comment: Expected array,compile error that's the error
i have tried changing my variables to long,integer, nothing worked dk why

Comment: Should the 3 lines starting REDIM to atomschange be outside the two loops?

Comment: When you get the error, hit the `Debug` and share which line is highlighted. That is the line to focus on.

Comment: he would just highlight the name of my array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You are redim'ing your arrays inside a loop which reinitializes, then dropping any data inside the array. Use the `PRESERVE` keyword to insure you don't dump your array when redimensioning it `ReDim Preserve atoms(0 To 20, 0 To 20)`
2. Redimensioning your arrays to the exact same size makes no sense. They are already `0 To 20, 0 To 20` because you already set that. Redim them *once* outside of your for loops and then leave them alone.
3. Insure that your `atoms` and `atomschange` arrays are declared properly at the top of your code. It's complaining (probably when you redim them) that those two variables aren't arrays.

You know the size of the arrays before this code executes, so declare them and dim them properly in the declaration, then just use them (removing the superfluous and incorrect use of `redim` in your loop:

```
Sub somesumroutine()
    Dim atoms(0 to 20, 0 to 20) as Integer
    Dim atomschange(0 to 20, 0 to 20) as Integer

    For j = 0 To 20
        For i = 0 To 20             
            atomschange(j, i) = 0

            If i Mod 2 = 0 And j Mod 2 = 0 Then
                [B2].Offset(j, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                atoms(j, i) = 1
            Else
                [B2].Offset(j, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
                atoms(j, i) = 0
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```

Consider using `UBound` and `LBound` of your `atoms` array to set the loops so you don't have to use the `0 to 20` over and over again. This way you can dim your arrays once and leave the rest of your code alone:

```
Sub somesumroutine()
    Dim atoms(0 to 20, 0 to 20) as Integer
    Dim atomschange(0 to 20, 0 to 20) as Integer

    For j = lBound(atoms, 1) To uBound(atoms, 1)
        For i = lBound(atoms, 2) To uBound(atoms, 2)            
            atomschange(j, i) = 0

            If i Mod 2 = 0 And j Mod 2 = 0 Then
                [B2].Offset(j, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                atoms(j, i) = 1
            Else
                [B2].Offset(j, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
                atoms(j, i) = 0
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, so I was right about two of the lines - must be improving... :) plus one from me.